# Submiting multiple forms at once aborts all the form submissions, except the last

Tags: javascript, jquery, devexpress

I hace an ASP.NET MVC application and I am using
[pivot grids](https://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxPivotGridDemos/DataOutput/Export) from dev express and i need to make an excell with the ones that are on one page. The documentation says that in order to export the pivot grid as it is on the page (keep the column colapse/expanded) you need to keep the pivot grid inside a form and submit it.

My problem is that when i submit all the forms on the page only one finishes and the others get canceled.
I have tried using the ajaxForm plugin but that doesn't keep the grid as it is on the page (all the columns are expanded).

My question is if you know of a way to submit my forms sequantially if the previous one has finished posting?

My forms look like this

```
<form class="table-content" method="post" target="excel-export-iframe" style="display: block;" action="url">
```

with a hidden iframe as the target

```
<iframe style="display: none" id="excel-export-iframe" name="excel-export-iframe"></iframe>
```

And this is the code for submiting them

```
$(".table-content").each(function () {
    $(this).submit();
});
```

Comment: You can only submit one form at a time using the standard method. If you need to submit more than one, you need to use AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up loading something in the target iframe then using the load the function to post the next form and so on

```
<form class="table-content" method="post" target="excel-export-iframe" style="display: block;" action="@Url.Action("ExcelExport")">
<iframe style="display: none" id="excel-export-iframe" name="excel-export-iframe"></iframe>

var submitArray;

$("#excel-export-iframe").load(function () {
    var status = $("#excel-export-iframe").contents().find("pre").text();
    if (status == "Post Successfull") {
        if (submitArray.length != 0) {                    
            $(submitArray .splice(0, 1)).submit();
        }
    }
});

$('.btn-export').click(function () {
    submitArray = $(".table-content");
    $(submitArray .splice(0, 1)).submit();
}
```

And in the controller I return this:

```
public ActionResult ExcelExport(...)
{
    ...
    return Content("<pre>Post Successfull</pre>");
}
```

I'm pretty sure this isn't the best practice but this serves my purposes and I couldn't find any other way to post multiple form considering that using Ajax was not an option

Answer (score 2):

As per the comment from @Rory

Use following AJAX code

```
$(".table-content").each(function () {
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    $.post('url', data);
});
```

Comment: if i use post the state of my pivot grid is not kept